# How can I fix a Wix 4 bundle installation where dialogs are not displayed?

Tags: bundle, wix4

How can I fix a Wix 4 bundle installation where dialogs are not displayed?

When installing directly from MSI (msiexec -i installer.msi ..) , installation succeeds.
When installing from the Wix 4 bundle (installer.exe), installation starts, but dialogs are not displayed, and the installation fails.

My bundles.wxs contains:

```
<MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="Installer.msi" 
    bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="WixBundleExecutePackageAction = 2"  
    EnableFeatureSelection="yes" 
    Vital="yes" 
    Compressed="yes" />
```

The installation log file (located in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp....log) has:

Condition 'WixBundleExecutePackageAction = 2' evaluates to false.

I guess that 'false' value for bal:DisplayInternalUICondition explains why dialogs are not displayed.

Changing bundle code to bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="true" didn't work
Also tried to set WixBundleExecutePackageAction to 2, but this didn't work either.

( I am using ThemeFile="RtfTheme.xml"  , not sure if this is relevant )

What am I doing wrong?
What should be fixed in order to display the installer dialogs?

Thanks in advance,
Ofer

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="1"
```